# How to enable mousewheel in chrome?

Tags: javascript, mousewheel, preventdefault

I disable mousewheel with javascript, when i scroll the page to the special block. 
I use a lot of methods, but all of them worked in firefox, not in chrome. 
For chrome i find a specital method with preventDefault. 
But i don't know how to enable them.
This is the code:

```
const options = {
    rootMargin: "-400px"
};

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(function (entries, observer) {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
        console.log(entry.isIntersecting);
        if (entry.isIntersecting === true) {
            document.querySelector('body').classList.add('fixed');
            document.body.addEventListener('wheel', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }, {passive: false});

            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: scrollCenter
            }, 1000);

            setTimeout(function () {
                document.querySelector('body').classList.remove('fixed');
                document.body.addEventListener('wheel', function (e) {
                    // override prevented flag to prevent jquery from discarding event
                    e.isDefaultPrevented = function () {
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }, 1000);

        }
    });
}, options);

observer.observe(produtsBlock);
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stacking up a listener to invalidate a previous listener is tricky as they are fired in FIFO sequence.

Some options:

#### 1. Removing the listener

You could remove the blocking listener after that period of time.

With a named function:

```js
const prevent = (e) => e.preventDefault();
document.body.addEventListener('wheel', prevent, { passive: false });
```

You can remove it afterwards:

```js
setTimeout(function () {
  document.querySelector('body').classList.remove('fixed');
  document.body.removeEventListener('wheel', prevent);
}, 1000);
```

#### 2. Using a flag

Use a state flag to handle `preventDefault`.

```js
const state = { prevent: true };

const prevent = (e) => {
  if (state.prevent) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
};

document.body.addEventListener("wheel", prevent, { passive: false });
```

Then alter the flag:

```js
setTimeout(function () {
  document.querySelector("body").classList.remove("fixed");
  state.prevent = false;
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Please, do not forget to check this one as the selected answer, so it is marked as answered. Thanks @serii :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, but i don't understand, how to select you answer as selected?

Comment: You can Vote a question and Accept it. This article explains those concepts: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) Hope it helps :)

Comment: Sorry, but i think, i don't have a privelegies for a vote, or accept answers. I don't see the so options.

Comment: I have reputation 11, but must to be 15 for accepting and voting))